# Is there any difference between shards of a database and Elasticsearch?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, sharding

I am under the impression the former has a method to the madness, while the latter is random.

Comment: exactly what difference you want to know, can you explain more ? help us to help you.

Comment: Technically, a database shard can be a horizontal slice. May be a US address database sharded on zipcode. Can't really compare a Lucene index to this DB but is there some method to sharding when it comes to ElasticSearch

Comment: Tried explaining with some official link, let me know if you have follow up question

Answer (score 0):

Example you mentioned to shard a DB based on zipcode can also be achieved in Elasticsearch, and As far as I know in RDBMS also you need some sort of configuration to shard the data based on zipcode(your example), similar way in Elasticsearch also you can achieve it using the [routing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-shard-routing.html#search-routing).

If you don't specify the routing value, then Elasticsearch uses its own consistent hashing to determine which shards document needs to be stored and using this it routes the search request to the shards that contains the data.

Hope this helps.